# Use json from API (loaded in PHP) in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json, api, curl

I have a question about using json (loaded in php) in javascript.
I load the JSON from an API. Someone said I could best do this with curl?

I've searched information about curl but I didn't found what I needed. 
This is what I do now:

```
$url='http://api.urlname.com/api/gateway/call/1.4/getApp?appid=2631';
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($str);
```

Does someone know how I can do this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: What's the problem?  If this works, then why do you need to use cURL?  Also, what does this have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, cURL is more advanced than just using `file_get_contents`, you can do lots of things with cURL.

If we rewrite your code and make it use cURL, it'd look like this:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://api.urlname.com/api/gateway/call/1.4/getApp?appid=2631");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$str = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($str);
```

as I said cURL is a pretty customizable, if you wish to go farther and do complex requests, you can always see the [documentations here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: And how can I use that json data in my javascript code?

Comment: @niels123 I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Are you calling this PHP function via AJAX? If that's your case, then just echo the JSON data from PHP.